# How to change row height for selected row in wpf DataGrid programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
{
    dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
}

if (dep != null && dep is DataGridRow)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dep;

    row.Height = 35;
}
```

with this code selected row's height changed but row content height doesn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with style also,

```
<Style x:Key="PrettierDataGridStyle" TargetType="dg:DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="CellStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="dg:DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <!-- Highlight selected rows -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="height" Value="35"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```